# Regex PCRE: Validate string to match first set of string instead of last

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I tried quite a few things but Im stuck with my regex whenever meets the criteria 2 consecutive times. In this case it just considers it as one expressions instead of 2.

```
\[ame\=[^\.]+(.+)youtube\.(.+)v\=([^\]\&\"]+)[\]\'\"\&](.+)\[\/ame\]
```

E.g.

> [ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brfr5CD2qqY"][B][COLOR=yellow]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brfrx5D2qqY[/COLOR][/B][/ame][/U]
>   [B][COLOR=yellow]or[/COLOR][/B] [B][COLOR=yellow]B[/COLOR][/B]
>   [ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9ak3rKIBAU"][B][COLOR=yellow]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9a3arKIBAU[/COLOR][/B][/ame]
>   [B][COLOR=yellow]or[/COLOR][/B] [B][COLOR=yellow]C[/COLOR][/B]
>   [ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vh--3pyq5U"][COLOR=yellow]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vh--3pyq5U[/COLOR][/ame]

In that case, this regex would instead of matching all 3 options, it takes it as one.

Any ideas how to make an expression that would say match the first `"[/ame]"`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always try to simplify your examples so they are small and easier to understand. Also make it clearer what you get and what you actually get. In this case, if you make every `+` non-greedy as `+?` does it not solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `.+` -  they are "greedy", meaning they will consume as much input as possible and still match.

Change them to *reluctant* quantifiers: `.+?`, which won't skip forward over the end of the first match to match the end if the last match.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant period instead of the comma but i think i got it to work. The problem was that even with the reluctant quantifiers, I was using the s modifier at the end which was still causing it to match the entire string instead of stopping at the first ame].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your objective is (you haven't made that clear yet)

But this will match and capture out the youtube URL for you, ensuring you only match each single instance between `[ame=` and `[/ame]`

`/\[ame=["'](.*?)["'](.*?)\/ame\]/i`

Here's a working example, and a great sandbox to play around in: http://regex101.com/r/jR4lK2

Comment: Thanks, used my original example except used your ".*?". Your example includes a lot of non-youtube urls and it did not work great for me. Also, nice regex site for testing!

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure what you wanted to capture or not, biggest part was definitely the non-greedy .*?.  Regex101 is awesome! Good luck

Comment: Actually, try this one: `\[ame=["'](.*?youtu\.?be.*?)["'](.*?)\/ame\]` matches only youtube and youtu.be

Comment: The "./" before the be is a great suggestion, i definitely added it to my regex.

BTW, The plan (which i did not explain well at first) is to convert:

Comment: [ame=(Can have ", www, https:// or may not)youtube.com/watch?v=<Important video ID after the v=><After the id it can have ", & or most other characters except [ or ]>](just about any characters can go here except /)[/ame]

Then i convert that to: [media=youtube]<This is the important id>[/media]

Comment: For the above, the best option was still: #\[ame\=[^\.]+(.+?)youtu\.?be\.?(.+)v\=([^\]\&\"\[]+)[\]\'\"\&](.*?)\[\/ame\]#iu